# Calibration of parametric multi-agent simulation to be consistent with emergent stylized facts

Tags: simulation, calibration

I've created a market simulation with a few different types of agents that trade with each other based on simple rules that sample from parametrized random distributions.

I can choose reasonable values for the parameters by hand, but there are too many (a few dozen) and their interactions too complex to easily make the market's emergent behavior consistent with observed stylized facts (e.g., typical price volatility, distribution of event arrival times, etc.).

I'm surprised to not find much literature on this topic.  Are there any relevant references?  My first thought is to use a derivative-free reinforcement learning method to optimize the parameters relative to a heuristic objective that combines all desired stylized facts.*  Is this a reasonable approach?

* To clarify: my simulated agents would not learn to increase their own fitness.  The objective of the learning would only be to make their collective behavior more consistent with reality.